# Equivalent Generating set for Borel Sigma Algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How can I show that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra can be written as $\sigma(\{(-\infty,y]:y\in\mathbb{R}\}$? I know that it is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. I have quite elementary knowledge of measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you know that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is generate by the open intervals so you need to show that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ that under countable unions, complements, etc you can get any open interval from the half closed rays. To that end let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. You know that $(- \infty ,a ] , (-\infty, b] \in \sigma(\{(-\infty,y]: y \in \mathbb{R}\})$. Taking their intersection you get $[a,b]$ where we are assuming $a < b$.

So we have that closed intervals are in your sigma algebra. Then we can get the open interval $(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]}$. This is back in you $\sigma$ -algebra as it is a countable union of sets in your $\sigma$-algebra.

So if $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel Sigma algebra generated by open sets what have we show? We have shown that $\sigma(\{(-\infty,y]: y \in \mathbb{R} \}) \subset \mathcal{B}$. So lastly, we need to show that $\mathcal{B} \subset \sigma(\{(-\infty,y]: y \in \mathbb{R} \})$.

However, this is not very hard. Let $(-\infty,y] \in \sigma(\{(-\infty,y]: y \in \mathbb{R} \})$. Then $(-\infty,y] =\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-n,y+\frac{1}{k})}$. Which is a countable union and intersection and hence is in $\mathcal{B}$. Thus, we have shown that $\mathcal{B} \subset \sigma(\{(-\infty,y]: y \in \mathbb{R} \})$, and we have equality.

Every nonempty open subset is a disjoint union of a countable collection of open intervals.

Proof: Let $O \subset \mathbb{R}$ open and nonempty. Let $x \in O$ there is a $y > x$ such that $(x,y) \subset O$ and $z< x$ such that $(z,x) \subset O$. Define the extended real numbers $a_x,b_x$ by $a_x= \inf \{z: (z,x) \subset O\}$ and $b_X = \sup\{y: (x,y) \subset O\}$. Then we have that $I_x=(a_x,b_x)$ is an open interval containing x. We claim that $I_x \subset O$ but $a_X,b_x \notin O$. Let $w \in I_x$ say $x < w < b_X$. By definition of $b_x$ there is a number $y > w$ such that $(x,y) \subset O$ and so $w \in O$. Moreover, $b_x \notin O$. If it were then for some $r > 0$ we would have that $(b_X -r, b_x +r) \subset O$ thus, $(x,b_x+r) \subset O$, contradicting the definition of O. Similarly, you can argue to show that $a_x \notin O$. Consider the collection of open intervals $\{I_x\}_{x \in O}$. Since each $I_x \subset O$ we have that $O=\bigcup_{x \in O}{I_x}$. It is clear that these intervals are disjoint. Now, using the density of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$ each of these open intervals contains a rational number and we can establish a 1-1 correspondence between the collection of open intervals and a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, O is a union of countable disjoint collection of open intervals.

Comment: Please note that th OP tell that in his definition, Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by open subsets (not intervals!) of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You can get every open subset as countable union of open intervals. This is basic analysis.

Comment: @AlecDiaz-Arias I definitely can. But you write an answer not for me, but for OP.

Comment: I don't know if you're talking to me or NCh but I do not need that at all.

Comment: @Python_Learner, now it is trival to see that your definition and the one I use for the Sigma algebra will also coincide.